# Regular expression to split by a specific occurrence of a token while ignoring other occurrences

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this :

```
String foo = "James Padolsky , Jimmy\\,Hoffa , Jane"
```

A regular split with `,` will result in Jimmy\,Hoffa being split too.

So it will be

> 1. `James Padolsky`
> 2. `Jimmy\`
> 3. `Hoffa`
> 4. `Jane`

What I need is

> 1. `James Padolsky`
> 2. `Jimmy\,Hoffa`
> 3. `Jane`

So the regex should ignore `\,` and only split by `,`
What regular expression will give me the above split ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\\),
```

As a Java string, that would be `"(?<!\\\\),"`.

Comment: Works great . The actual expression is foo.split("(?<!\\\\),");

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution with required comma and optional spaces:

```
String foo = "James Padolsky , Jimmy\\,Hoffa , Jane";
String[] splitted = foo.split("\\s?,\\s?");
for (String split: splitted) {
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Output:

```
James Padolsky
Jimmy\,Hoffa
Jane
```

Note: the double escape on your backslash in `foo`. Otherwise your `String` initialization would not compile.